# ajax: updating without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

http://pastebin.com/bnMaxjep

http://www.vidyasocks.com/index.php

See the ticker at the bottom, I want to update that so it shows without having the users refresh the page. I am using ajax to do it.

How do I do it? This is my first time using it.

Comment: On a side note you have errors in your html `"target="_blank"` needs spaces between `"` and `target` and you have a closing `</object>` tag but no opening one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main page would go something like this:

```
<?php session_start(); 

$_SESSION['visitcount']=0;

?>
<script>
function runcounter()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("counterelement").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","counter.php",true);
//may need these:
var params="id=testdata";
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
//need rest
xmlhttp.send();

setTimeout("runcounter()",1000); //refresh function every second

}
</script>
<body onload="runcounter()" >

<div id="counterelement">0</div>
```

This would update the function (counter) every second and run once on page load as well.

PHP:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['visitcount']++;
echo $_SESSION['visitcount'];
```

Comment: Where would I place this? Only thing I am unsure about

Comment: Alright, now I am confused. My ajax code is not working. How should it look? I want it to call the "'$text' from the db" if that makes sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10869/discussion-between-garrett-robertson-and-event-horizon)

Comment: @GarrettRobertson I realized you were attempting to do something different from my original Idea but if you need any further AJAX help ask, the AJAX I have posted here shows a simple counter calling to a PHP page for the code and posting it back to the original page.